# import error in custom python package

Tags: python, scrapy

While reorganizing a scrapy project I want to create a package from my `pipelines.py` file.

I want to change this...

```
├── my_scraper
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── items.py
│   ├── pipelines.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   └── spiders
└── scrapy.cfg
```

to this...

```
├── my_scraper
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── items.py
    │   ├── pipelines
    │   │   ├── __init__.py
    │   │   ├── MyPipeline1.py
    │   │   ├── MyPipeline2.py
    │   │   └── MyPipeline3.py
    │   ├── settings.py
    │   └── spiders
    └── scrapy.cfg
```

But after importing each pipeline class in `pipelines/__init__.py`

```
from my_pipeline1 import MyPipeline1
from my_pipeline2 import MyPipeline2
from my_pipeline3 import MyPipeline3
```

in and referencing each in `settings.py`

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
'my_scraper.pipelines.MyPipeline1': 100,
'my_scraper.pipelines.MyPipeline2': 200,
'my_scraper.pipelines.MyPipeline3': 300,

}
```

Now when I run `scrapy crawl my_scraper` I get the error...

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "/Users/path/to/my_scraper/pipelines/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
        from my_pipeline1 import MyPipeline1
    ImportError: No module named 'my_pipeline1'
```

Not sure how I should approach this after in order to make my code maintainable in the long run. Any tips / help are appreciated!

Comment: are you sure about the 'my_scraper1" ??? if yes, indeed, you only have MyPipeline1, MyPipeline2 and MyPipeline3 in pipelines.__init__

Answer (score 1):

> But after importing each pipeline class in pipelines/**init**.py

```
from my_pipeline1 import MyPipeline1
from my_pipeline2 import MyPipeline2
from my_pipeline3 import MyPipeline3
```

Looking at your project tree it seems like the above is completely unnecessary, in fact you don't even have anything named `my_pipeline1`.

So just get rid of these lines in `pipelines/__init__.py`.
You can nest and have multiple packages in your package. In this case you have `my_spider` package which in itself contains `spiders` and `pipelines` packages, so you can safely import them with:

```
from myspider.pipelines.pipelines1 import SomeClass
# or in settings as
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'myspider.pipelines.pipelines1.MyPipeline': 100,
}
```

Comment: @Zach No problem, feel free to click "accept answer" button to the left if you find the answer sufficient enough :)